# Are UIViewController view's subviews automatically preserved and restored or not?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to understand how the state preservation and restoration works.
I've read the books, tutorials, etc. Some things just escape my understanding.
Here's one of this. I've got a UIViewController with a proper restorationIdentifier.

In its `viewDidLoad()` function I'm adding an UITableView as a subview of the VC's view.
Like this:

```
tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: .Plain)
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
view.addSubview(tableView)
```

What I cannot understand is whether the view and its subviews of the VC are automatically preserved
and restored. In other words do I have to create the VC view's subview every
time in the `viewDidLoad()` or I should check if the subviews of the VC's view exist?

When I first read about the state preservation and restoration I thought that
a VC's views hierarchy (its view and the view's subviews) is preserved automatically. But now I'm not sure about
that. `view.subviews.count` always returns 0 (zero) when called in `viewDidLoad()`.

What do I misunderstand?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/):

When preserved, a view controller preserves the state of any views in its view hierarchy that also have restoration identifiers. View controllers do not automatically save any other state. If you are implementing a custom container view controller, you must encode any child view controllers yourself. Each child you encode must have a unique restoration identifier.

Note that you don't need to decode these child view controllers as iOS will do that automatically for you.

Example (in Swift):

```
override func encodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
    // container views are encoded manually
    for (i, vc) in enumerate(childViewControllers) {
        coder.encodeObject(vc, forKey:"rootchildvc\(i)")
    }

    super.encodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder)
}
```